# Prevent webbrowser control loading javascript from certain domain

Tags: javascript, c#, webbrowser-control, fiddler, fiddlercore

I'm loading a html page into a C# webbrowser object. There are links to some remote javascript files between script tags in the html page. One of them has a number of errors which I can't remedy as I can't change the javascript. As it's not needed, I'd rather disable it.

I would like to stop the webbrowser loading any javascript from a particular domain or just have the browser be returned a '404' for that javascript file. This can be done in Fiddler with the Autoresponder.

Is there any way to do this in C#? Like a mini-proxy forwarding all requests except those to *.domainwitherrors.com? Failing that, is there there a way to use Fiddler directly in C#?

Trapping the 'Navigating' event in the webbrowser doesn't catch the javascript before it's loaded into the DOM.

```
   webBrowser1.Navigate("http://www.somedomain.com");
   webBrowser1.Navigating += webBrowser1_Navigating;

    void webBrowser1_Navigating(object sender, WebBrowserNavigatingEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Url.ToString().Contains("domainwitherrors"))
        {
            return;
        }
```

}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, the WebBrowser control doesn't offer any request filtering mechanisms that would allow you to prevent subdownloads from only one domain. You *could* add the domain to your restricted sites zone (which will block its ability to run script in *every* IE-based browser on your system) using IE's Tools > Internet Options > Security tab.

[FiddlerCore](http://www.telerik.com/fiddler/fiddlercore) is a .NET class library that can be embedded into applications to provide exactly the sort of functionality you're describing. You can even use the `URLMonInterop.SetProxyInProcess` API it exposes so that only your application (and not the system as a whole) routes its traffic through the proxy.

Comment: While not trivial, it should still be possible to register an in-process [Asynchronous Pluggable handler](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/aa767916%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) for HTTP and/or HTTPS URL filtering and use WinInet to implement it. Is it not?

Comment: @Noseratio: I considered mentioning this, but it's both non-trivial and not technically supported by Microsoft. Every single attempt at this we've seen has been a source of security and reliability bugs.

Comment: Eric, fair enough. I remember experementing with pluggable ptotocols in pre-IE9 era and it was indeed a bumpy road.